# Bulk import nested records from ElasticSearch in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I would like to import a lot of data from ElasticSearch into RethinkDB, but I'm not sure if the import capability allows for the case when the json objects I want are nested within another object. In my case, ElasticSearch nests the "hits" inside query metadata

```
{"took":7453,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":11853,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[...]}}
```

I want to quickly input everything inside ["hits"]["hits"]. Is this possible?